# Find the AVERAGE of a range of adjacent cells after finding specific value(s)

Tags: excel

I have a file that each row shows the Monday date on one column (C) and the Sunday date on another column (D). Columns (E)-(S) show the sales for each store for each week. I am looking to get the average weekly store sales for the past 6 months and the formula consistently update looking for the most recent 6 months from a specific date which i enter in Cell (A1). I understand i would have to make a unique formula for each column (E)-(S) to get this average per store.

I have figured out how to get the date for the Sunday of the week for the date i enter in (A1). here is what i got and this is entered in (B1)...

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=1,A1,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=2,A1-1,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=3,A1-2,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=4,A1-3,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=5,A1-4,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=6,A1-5,IF(WEEKDAY(A1,11)=7,A1-6,"error")))))))
```

This will always get me a date that should appear on my (C) Column.

Example for 1st store in Column (E)...So the puzzle is for the formula to find this Monday date using formula above, then sum the sales in column (E) for the last 6 months. To get the starting date for the range of the 6 months, I simply use this =A1-168. I got the 168 by figuring out that there are on avg. 4 weeks per month * months. (=7*4*6) This will always display a Start date that is on column (C).

In short, i just want the avg of sales of (A1).

Comment: Do you want 6 month to start based on A1 or the Monday that A1 produces in C1?

Comment: From the that Monday that A1 produces

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by tightening up your multiple IF formula.

```
=IFERROR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1,11)+1, "error")    <~~ for Monday
=IFERROR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1,11), "")           <~~ for Sunday
```

This should give you the starting Monday or Sunday of any week that you supply a date to.

The [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) can quickly produce a date that is exactly six months previous. The [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) and [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) can produce totals and means based on that time window.

```
=SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, "<="&A1, A:A, ">"&EDATE(A1, -6))
=AVERAGEIFS(E:E, A:A, "<="&A1, A:A, ">"&EDATE(A1, -6))
```

There is some confusion as to whether to create the time window with A1 (the date), C1 (the Monday) or D1 (the Sunday) but you should be able to transcribe the methods used in these formulas for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jeeped. Very much appreciated. Learned a few things!!